# Could not run web test on agent TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, performance-testing

I'm running into an issue with data binding Web Performance tests. I have two web tests each databound to different CSV files. The first one created initially is running perfectly. But the second web test is throwing the following.

**error**:

```
Could not run Web test 'WebTest1' on agent {{SERVER}}: Could not access table 'Data#csv' in data source '{{Datasource}}' of test '6181b289-71fa-478f-8341-eba270b46c2a': No value given for one or more required parameters.
```

I'm running them locally. No Controllers or Agents are setup and I'm using `VS 2010 SP1`.

Answer (score 1):

Open the CSV file in the visual studios that is loaded in the web test and change the separator from `;` to `,` for both header and values. For example:

Before:

```
username;password;shopID;periodID
user1;password11;1;10
user2;password22;2;10
```

After:

```
username,password,shopID,periodID
user1,password11,1,10
user2,password22,2,10
```

Answer (score 1):

I received the above error after creating my .CVS file from the results of a SQL Server query.  After inspecting the .CVS with Notepad I found it was formatted as UTF-8.  From Notepad simply set the Encoding to ANSI instead of UTF-8 or Unicode and this will resolve the problem.

Comment: This worked but the other way around. I had to save in UTF-8 to get it working. The csv file was already ANSI format which was failing..